# How can i draw hexagon in 2d and able to scale it?

Tags: lua, love2d, roblox

So i made simple drawing script

[image]

This is what u can draw with it :D

[image]

So anyway my question is i wan't to make Erase Tool i already made one but it only removes 1 pixel at time instead i want to make hexagon thing and able to scale it up i just need formula to do that or simple explanation no script required

I want to be look like here I can just fill up pixels but i am not sure about how to deal with scaling part.

[image]

Comment: Vector art as compared to pixel art which is what you are doing there. http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/how-create-vector-art-2131975

Comment: I wasn't talking about drawing part actually i need programming part

Comment: The figure on your last picture is an octagon, not hexagon.  Anyway, it is parametrized by only 1 parameter - length of its side.  It is simple to calculate all its vertices if you know its center and its side length.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm extremely late, but if anybody else needs this help in the future, here's the solution.

You can simply loop for every pixels (a for loop for each y coordinates [as j] embedded in a for loop for each x coordinates [as i]).

Then for each of those loops, check the distance from the cursor's current position to the pixel located at (i, j), and if it's smaller than the chosen radius, change the pixel for a blank one.

The recommended way of checking the distance between two pixels in Roblox would be something like so:

```
(Vector2.new(x1, y1) - Vector2.new(x2, y2)).magnitude
```